# Corner Ribbon CSS

Tags: html, css

I need a bit of help with a CSS corner ribbon.

Basically I need the text to go over two lines and having a bit of a problem with getting the correct positioning.

Can anyone please help me out. Been trying for hours.

Here is a JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/9681/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">The Flagship Programme of<br />Aaaaa Aaaaaa Aaaaaaaaa</div></div>
</div>

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

With reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/

Comment: You should include a link to the [**article you took code from**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/) for our reference next time. Especially when it seems you've not changed much at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do, can be done using `white-space: nowrap` in elements styles you don't want to break into lines unless you want to. Here is the full code worked for me:

```
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 180px;
height: 172px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -4px;
right: -4px;
}

.ribbon-green {
font: bold 12px Sans-Serif;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
position: relative;
padding: 7px 0;
left: -5px;
top: 45px;
width: 235px;
background-color: #BFDC7A;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
color: #6a6340;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can view it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/9687/

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted the height and width of the ribbon-wrapper-green to be propotional to my new height of ribbon-green and then I moved the top of ribbin-green down.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/jFzHY/

```
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 227px;
  height: 237px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -15px;
  top: 65px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```